# MVC 4 model values not passed to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have view and want to display content from the object stored in session one by one when user clicks on NEXT button. View uses `WorldModel` object to display the data. Id is hidden field and Content should be displayed on page.

View:

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.WorldModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View1";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>View1</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Content)
        <input type="submit" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Model: This class contains two properties id and content. Basically id is mapped to candidate id and Content is mapped to candidate name.

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Models
{
    public class WorldModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller: Class has two action methods one doesn’t take any parameter and other takes `WorldModel` as parameter.

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class WorldController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /World/

        public ActionResult View1()
        {
            List<Candidate> obj = new List<Candidate>();
            obj.Add(new Candidate() { Id = 1, Name = "ABCD", IsNameDispalyed = false});
            obj.Add(new Candidate() { Id = 2, Name = "PQR", IsNameDispalyed = false });
            obj.Add(new Candidate() { Id = 3, Name = "XYZ", IsNameDispalyed = false });

            CandidateSession cs = new CandidateSession(){Candidates=obj};
            Session["Can"] = cs;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult View1(WorldModel worldModel)
        {
            CandidateSession cs = (CandidateSession)Session["Can"];
            var can1 = cs.Candidates.Where(x => x.IsNameDispalyed == false).First();
            can1.IsNameDispalyed = true;
            return View(new WorldModel() {Id=can1.Id, Content=can1.Name });
        }
    }

    public class Candidate
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsNameDispalyed { get; set; }
    }

    public class CandidateSession
    {
        public List<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I access URL as `“../World/View1”` it fills data to session object and click on NEXT button calls the action `public ActionResult View1(WorldModel worldModel)`. In the method I get the object whose info is not displayed return the view with `WorldModel` object with id and Content. Now first time the Content is displayed but when the I click on NEXT button it call action `public ActionResult View1(WorldModel worldModel)`. But the id and Content values of worldModel object are null. Why data is null, I set the values in the previous call?

Comment: because the second time the button is clicked, the modelstate has had some values, namely nulls to bind up with.  I would call ModelState.Clear() before returning the view from the HttpPost

Comment: @Slicksim: I didn't get. Actually Controller is setting the values of Model which bind to view. Now When user click on Next button it hits the action there I wanted get the values that are stored in previous request.